# Issues with my Meteor TelescopeApp Application

Tags: meteor, telescope

Okay so this is the current error I appear to be receiving.

```
error: standard-minifiers, seba:minifiers-autoprefixer: multiple packages registered minifiers for extension "js".


error: standard-minifiers, seba:minifiers-autoprefixer: multiple packages registered minifiers for extension "css".
```

Simple solution right?! So I thought until I removed the standard-minifiers, and then ran into a new error.

For some reason it wasn't compiling my SCSS into CSS and pulling the includes.

Here is the next error I received:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:                  

While processing files with fourseven:scss (for target web.browser):
/packages/opinurate-branding/lib/client/stylesheets/custom.scss: Scss compiler error: File to import: {opinurate-branding}/lib/client/stylesheets/variables not found in file: /home/jonathan/Projects/cx.io/app/{opinurate-branding}/lib/client/stylesheets/custom.scss
```

I'm afraid to do anything further, so I undid everything and am now back to the original error.

I don't know enough about the TelescopeApp and the documentation (found at https://telescope.readme.io/docs) is vague.

I am unable to delete the seba:minifiers-autoprefixer for some reason, and I had assumed it might work if I was somehow able to remove this. I believe it came with the 0.25 update.

I am desperate for some sort of support here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you run into a package conflict with Telescope you can delete your `.meteor/versions` file to force Meteor to use each package's latest version.

Comment: Is this really advisable? Wouldn't that mean losing all the packages version info?

Comment: That doesn't really matter. But anyway, if you're worried about that you can always make a backup of that file first.